# get_absolute_url() depending on attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I am trying to return the url only if the condition is true but It looks like Django not allows this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.display_personal_page:
        return reverse('users:detail', args=[self.slug])
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: What do you mean that Django doesn't allow it? Are you getting an error (if so, could you share the error message and traceback in the question)?

Comment: I receive a error when the function return None and when the function return a empty string, in Django's admin "View on site" still appears.
 
Django wants a string but I want to define this function only if the condition is true.

Comment: What do you mean, it wants a string? Where does it want a string? *What error do you see?*

Comment: You changed your comment after I responded to it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't use what's returned from `get_absolute_url` to determine whether or not to show the View on site link. However, it does provide a [`get_view_on_site_url`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L289) method on the ModelAdmin class, and that's what you should override to create your logic.